# php while mysql_fetch_array inside while

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i have this part of a code and i cant understund why the second loop inside the first does not work. I query two tables and i placed an echo inside the second table to see if it echo's but it does not either . thanx in advance

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a class=\"s03\" href=" . $row['link'] . "><span>". $row['onomaselidas'] ."</span></a>\n";
 echo "<ul class=\"pn2\">\n";
 $idd[]=$row['idwebsiteprimary'];
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
   {
    echo "test";
   if($idd[$url]==$row2['idwebsite'])
    {
    echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a href=\"a\"><span>". $row2['name'] ."</span></a></li>\n";
    }
   }
 echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the query for $result2 is returning rows?

Comment: Where is the code for that query and that result-set? Also, does it return something?

Comment: oh my god i am so stupid, i was having the wrong query.
but now i have another broblem if the $url equals to 1 i get
"Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first iteration of the first loop, the internal pointer of the second result set is at the end, so the second loop will not execute, because `mysql_fetch_array()` will return `false` immediately. If you want to it exactly as above - the second result set is not dependant on the first - you will need to do this:

```
// First, get the results of set 2 into an array
$resultset2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) $resultset2[] = $row;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Do your thang
  echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a class=\"s03\" href=" . $row['link'] . "><span>".$row['onomaselidas'] ."</span></a>\n";
  echo "<ul class=\"pn2\">\n";
  $idd[] = $row['idwebsiteprimary'];
  foreach ($resultset2 as $row2) { // Foreach sets it's pointer to the beginning every time, so this should work
    echo "test";
    if ($idd[$url]==$row2['idwebsite']) {
      echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a href=\"a\"><span>". $row2['name'] ."</span></a></li>\n";
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you can reset the internal pointer of `$result2` on each iteration of the first loop by calling [`mysql_data_seek($result2, 0);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a class=\"s03\" href=" . $row['link'] . "><span>". $row['onomaselidas'] ."</span></a>\n";
  echo "<ul class=\"pn2\">\n";
  $idd[] = $row['idwebsiteprimary'];
  mysql_data_seek($result2, 0);
  while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "test";
    if($idd[$url]==$row2['idwebsite']) {
      echo "<li class=\"s01\"><a href=\"a\"><span>". $row2['name'] ."</span></a></li>\n";
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
}
```